# How to group data by days in MongoDB + PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have some collection:

```
$data_to_insert = array('date'=> $current_date, 'str_date' => $today_date_str, 'user_id' => intval($post->post_author), 'post_id' => $post->ID, 'user_ip' => current_user_ip());
```

And I take some data from mongo database(it's working):

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("-14 days"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));

$last_day_query = $hits_collection->find(array("date" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end), "user_id" => $current_user->ID));
```

How I need modify my query to get data grouped by days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ops = array(
                array(
                        '$match' => array(
                                            'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
                                            'date' => array(
                                                            '$gt' => $start, 
                                                            '$lte' => $end
                                                            ) 
                                        ),
                    ),
                array(
                        '$project' =>array(
                                            'date' => 1, 
                                            'user_id' => 1
                                            ), 
                        '$group' => array('_id' => '$str_date', 'views' => array('$sum' => 1)),
                ),

    );

    $result = $hits_collection->aggregate($ops);
```

Comment: Not sure why this has two up votes he doesn't even explain what he is doing. Also this only works if you assume that `str_date` is on day and also you don't need the `$project` either, in fact this aggregation won't work because of the way that documents are passed from the project to the group.

Comment: It's really working :) In str_date I have "2013-03-03"-like data.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and $group operator, like this:

```
$result = $collection->aggregate([
    ['$match' => ['date' => ['$gt' => $start, '$lt' => $end]]],
    ['$group' => ['_id' => ['date' => '$date']]]
]);
```

But it groups by pure date. You can use $dayOfMonth operator for grouping by day:

```
['$group' => ['_id' => ['date' => ['$dayOfMonth' => '$date']]]]
```